# Rails - MassAssignmentSecurity:: Error on multiple photo upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make a product page for a small app. This product page should allow the user to add multiple photos. So naturally there are three models. User, Product and Photo. User has_many products and products has_many photos.

All was dandy but whenever I try to add a number of photos I get this error.

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ProductsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: photos_attributes
```

**products controller**

```
  def new 
    @product = Product.new
    @photo = Photo.new
    4.times{ @product.photos.build }
  end

  def create
  @product = current_user.products.new(params[:product])
  @photo = current_user.photos.new(params[:photo])

    if @product.valid? && @photo.valid?
      @product.save
      @photo.product_id = @product.id
      @photo.save
        render "show", :notice => "Sale created!"
    else
        render "new", :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
    end
  end
```

**new product page**(HAML)

```
= form_for @product,:url => products_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  - if @product.errors.any?
    .error_messages
      %h2 Form is invalid
      %ul
        - for message in @product.errors.full_messages
          %li
            = message
  - if @photo.errors.any?
    .error_messages
      %h2 Image is invalid
      %ul
        - for message in @photo.errors.full_messages
          %li
            = message
  %p
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  %p
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description
  %p
    = f.fields_for :photos do |fp|
      =fp.file_field :image
      %br

  %p.button
    = f.submit
```

**Product Model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :price, :condition, :ship_method, :ship_price, :quantity, :photo
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Photo model**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image
  belongs_to :product
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>", :thumb => "100x100>"}
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "photos", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         :null => false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
  end

  create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

### Edit: when i add :photos_attributes to product model attr_accessible  i get an error that says Image can't be blank !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `photos_attributes` to the `attr_accessible` list in the Product model. Or even better, try to migrate to [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem, will save you sometime when you migrate to Rails 4.

**Update**

In `create` action, you create a `@photo` variable from `params[:photo]`, which is knows to return `nil`, yielding the object invalid always. That said, you don't need to create that variable as `Photo` objects are already made for as you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` already. I understand that you need to know if the `Photo`s are created successfully, but you shouldn't be worrying about it as errors from product's new photos will propagate to the product, stopping the saving process.

Comment: when i add :photos_attributes to product model attr_accessible i get an error that says Image can't be blank !!

Comment: in the beginning of the form i have   - if @photo.errors.any?
    .error_messages
      %h2 Image is invalid

Comment: Can you please post the output of this line `@photos.errors.full_messages`? Or "image can't be blank" is it's output?

Comment: that is the output for some reason

Comment: check out the edit. I filled in how my new product page looks with error messages